# Angular unable to store jwt token on IOS devices

Tags: ios, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am using the following:

- Angular 7.2.15
- django 2.1.7
- djangorestframework 3.9.1
- djangorestframework-jwt 1.11.0

I am storing a JWT token in localstorage and this works on computers and android phones (at least the ones i tested) but when i try to log in on an iPhone or iPad, it accepts the credentials and shows my landing page for a split second then throws a 401 unauthorized error and logs be back out (i have it set up to log out on 401 errors).

I did some debugging using the webtools with safari and it looks like my token is not getting stored and that would explain why i get the 401.

My login script is pretty simple

```
login(username, password) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/api-token-auth/`, { username, password })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            this._currentUserSubject.next(user);
            return user;
        }));
}
```

Any thoughts on how i can get this token to store on an iPhone/iPad?

Thanks in advance,
jAC

Comment: Are you sure, you are not clearing localstorage anywhere ?. And there are some known issues with IOS 5 & 6, You can read more here https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage (In **Known Issues** Tab)

Comment: @Sameer I clear the localstorage on logout. the issue is that it does not appear to be storing the token at all. Also, I am using IOS 13 and i am not worried about support legacy devices.